# Incorrect colors with vim in iTerm2 using Solarized

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme, iterm

I am having a strange issue with iTerm2, in terminal vim (non-gui) and the solarized color scheme. First, I have set iTerm2 to use the dark solarized colour scheme.

I am also using solarized for vim. I have the following lines in my .vimrc

```
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

In the terminal the color scheme looks incorrect:
[image: console vim]

For reference this is how it looks under MacVim (gui vim)
[image: gui vim]

What do I need to change in iTerm or my .vimrc to get the colors looking correctly in my console vim?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. In iTerm2, in Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal, under "Terminal Emulation" you have "Report Terminal Type:" set to xterm-256color.
2. In your .vimrc, there are some options you can also set to make sure it's using 256 colors:
   `set background=dark
   " solarized options 
   let g:solarized_visibility = "high"
   let g:solarized_contrast = "high"
   colorscheme solarized`

   And one of those should work, but #1 first.

BUT, if you're using the default, built in vim on Snow Leopard, it won't work, as it's not built with support for 256 colors. I believe the built in version in Lion does.

**Edit:** Based on several comments on this answer, I've removed `let g:solarized_termcolors = 256` line from the `.vimrc` example above. It appears that could be a problem for some. Another says that adding the line `let g:solarized_termcolors = 16` fixed a color display problem. Your own mileage may vary.

**Second Edit:** If you've loaded the solarized color palette into iTerm2, then you must `let g:solarized_termcolors=16`. Only `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` if you are *not* using the solarized palette as your iTerm2 color preset.

Comment: Actually, "let g:solarized_termcolors = 256" was the *cause* of solarized displaying incorrectly for me. Per the git repo (https://github.com/vim-scripts/Solarized), "IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:", you should "let g:solarized_termcolors=16".

Comment: If you are using the solarized color scheme with your terminal the 16 ANSI colors will be set to the solarized colors, in which case you want to set `let g:solarized_termcolors=16`. If you use 256 it will be close, but the background will be grey instead of the deep sea blue.

Comment: It seems like `256` gives me the gray background instead of dark blue on Lion but `16` looks exactly the same as omitting that variable from my vimrc. Oh well, dark gray is better than a really light gray that I was getting before.

Comment: @SaiPerchard comment should be added to the answer. For me this was what fixed the wrong background color.

Comment: Didn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12969298/1945990 did though. ITerm, solarized theme plus vim solarized theme.

Answer (score 95):

The above answers didn't work for me.

I'm using iTerm2 with vim 7.3 on OS X 10.7.4.

If the above solutions didn't work for you too, try this

```
syntax on
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
colorscheme solarized
```

Update: According to Jim Stewart, this works on [Kitty](http://kitty.9bis.net/) too.

Comment: I'm using KiTTY (PuTTY derivative) on Windows 7, and `let g:solarized_termtrans = 1` fixed an issue for me where the background color on blank lines was grey, but the background color on lines with text was black after the content.

Comment: they aren't black thuogh :(

Comment: If you're using any other color scheme, you can `hi Normal ctermbg=NONE`, since that's essentially what `termtrans` does in solarized (as far as I can tell from their source)

Comment: Works for me on OSX 10.9, iTerm2 1.0.0.20131109.

Comment: This is the closest to working, it sets the background colour correctly, but my cursorline, colorcolumn and line number column all have black background. Why is nothing ever easy!

Comment: The same here, created an issue https://github.com/altercation/ethanschoonover.com/issues/27

Comment: This worked for me as well - not sure if it makes a difference, but on OSX, I'm using tmux as well

Comment: This fixed it for me ty

Answer (score 13):

https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized

Download Solarized package (https://github.com/altercation/solarized) and follow instructions:

> Open iTerm 2, open Preferences, click on the "Profiles" (formerly Addresses, formerly Bookmarks) icon in the preferences toolbar, then select the "colors" tab. Click on the "load presets" and select "import...". Select the Solarized Light or Dark theme file.
>
> You have now loaded the Solarized color presets into iTerm 2, but
>   haven't yet applied them. To apply them, simply select an existing
>   profile from the profile list window on the left, or create a new
>   profile. Then select the Solarized Dark or Solarized Light preset from
>   the "Load Presets" drop down.

====================================

Or:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git
```

**Modify .vimrc**

Dark Theme:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

Light

```
syntax enable
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: None of the previous answers solves my problem but this one does. It turns out that what was missing for me was the color presets.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me in OS X 10.9.1 in iTerm 2 as well as Terminal. One mistake I was making was putting the colorscheme declaration before the termtrans and termcolors settings (and I needed both of these to make it work). As others have said, I set my terminal type to xterm-256color

```
if !has("gui_running")
    let g:solarized_termtrans=1
    let g:solarized_termcolors=256
endif

colorscheme solarized
set background=dark
```

Answer (score 7):

From the creator: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized

> IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:
>
> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI version like gvim or macvim), please please please consider setting your terminal emulator’s colorscheme to used the Solarized palette. I’ve included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from Solarized homepage. If you use Solarized without these colors, Solarized will need to be told to degrade its colorscheme to a set compatible with the limited 256 terminal palette (whereas by using the terminal’s 16 ansi color values, you can set the correct, specific values for the Solarized palette).
>
> If you do use the custom terminal colors, solarized.vim should work out of the box for you. If you are using a terminal emulator that supports 256 colors and don’t want to use the custom Solarized terminal colors, you will need to use the degraded 256 colorscheme. To do so, simply add the following line before the colorschem solarized line:

`let g:solarized_termcolors=256`

> Again, I recommend just changing your terminal colors to Solarized values either manually or via one of the many terminal schemes available for import.

Comment: This was the only way I could get iTerm2 to use the solarized colors in non-GUI MacVim.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with the same problem on OSX 10.11.6, iTerm2 Build 3.0.12.

Here is my fix for it.

1. .vimrc

   syntax enable
   set background=dark
   colorscheme solarized
2. Set Report Terminal Type to `xterm-256color`.

[image]

3. Set color preset in the profile to Solarized Dark

[image]

Comment: Upvote because this was the clue I needed to try different color presets that lead me to the discovery that color escape codes past 256 are treated differently on mac vs linux.  On mac, colors past 256 seemed to be modded than flattened to one of the 8 ANSI colors selected, wheras in linux appears to be doing a modulus which wraps around and picks a color.

Answer (score 4):

Bill Turner's answer works, but there is a way to get the colors to match MacVim exactly. Solarized has support specifically for iTerm2, among other terminal emulators.

1. Go to the [iterm2-colors-solarized github page](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized)
2. Follow the instructions under "Installation"
3. Make sure your .vimrc has the line `colorscheme solarized`

This should set the vim colors in iTerm2 to be exactly as they are in gui editors.

Comment: As the answer also suggests, Bill Turner's answer is also correct but THIS is the official(hence correct) way to set the `solarized` theme.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve this problem is:

In colors dir on vim-color-solarized exist an arquive named 'solarozed.vim'

Open this file and search:
exe "let s:bg_back      = ' ".s:vmode."bg=".s:back   ."'"

replace to:
exe "let s:bg_back      = ' ".s:vmode."bg=".s:none   ."'"

Answer (score 1):

For any still having issues like I was, I had installed iterm2 [solarized color profile](https://github.com/altercation/solarized). Installing [vim-color-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) to vim bundles and following the instructions was unnecessary and was incompatible. There were funny highlighting issues like in the screen capture above.

Lesson learned: don't do both.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the previous suggestions.  I just added `set t_Co=256` to .vimrc and it was fixed.  I didn't need to create a `tmux` alias or change my config file.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me. Apparently I was missing:

```
set termguicolors
```