# Vim + iTerm2 color issues

Tags: shell, vim, terminal, macvim, iterm

I have trouble with the right Vim configuration. I'm using the latest version of Vim as well as the latest version of iTerm2.

I try to get the solarized colorscheme working, but without luck so far.

Here you can see an image with (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right)
iTerm2, Terminal.app, MacVim and my iTerm2 settings.

[image: Vim(s)]

Here the link to my [.vimrc](http://pastebin.com/ynND8LRh)

Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: superuser :) they have plenty of vim related quesions

Comment: Seems there is a duplicate question there : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7278267/513198 Check if it solves your issue. There is plenty of other questions mentioning both vim and iterm2 regarding to color scheme.

Comment: I wish it would be a duplicate, but like you can see in my .vimrc, it's not

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the preset colors in iTerm. There are solarized presets: https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized

I think this just has to do with the way iTerm color themes work. Your .vimrc is fine.