# Background bleed + border inconsistencies in VIM, tmux, iTerm2 on OS X using solarized-dark

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme, tmux, iterm2

I describe two cases below which present oddities that I can't really wrap my head around.  I suspect it has to do with how many colours are allowed.  I also think that the issues (tmux background bleed and VIM borders) are actually two separate issues, but I have not been able to get them to occur simultaneously.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Case 1:** VIM only (in iTerm2)

The solarized dark color scheme appears as shown on the [official solarized website](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).  However, the pane borders in VIM are absent and lack color. For good measure, my `.vimrc` is open on the right pane.

[image: VIM only showing .vimrc]

**Case 2:** VIM + tmux (in iTerm2)

The background is almost always brighter than in *Case 1* except for some darker areas (which is what I expected to see in the first place.)  On the other hand, the pane borders in VIM appear normal and coloured. My `.tmux.conf` is open on the right pane.

[image: VIM + tmux showing .tmux.conf]

**Details**

VIM was installed via Mac Ports

- OS X 10.9.1

  - Upgraded from Mountain Lion
- iTerm2 1.0.0.20130622

  - iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Report Terminal Type: `xterm-256color`
  - Installed solarized theme
- VIM 7.4

  - Installed via Mac Ports
  - Installed solarized theme
  - `.vimrc` in first image
- tmux 1.8

  - Installed via Mac Ports
  - `.tmux.conf` in second image

**UPDATE 1:** I have managed to fix the background bleeding issue because I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized) on StackOverflow.  Jason Yeo's solution worked for me (the accepted and most upvoted solution by Seyeong Jeong did not work for me.)

Comment: iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Report Terminal Type: xterm-256color is reported when in iTerm. But when you launch tmux is it still showing the same?